# Migrate all keys one database to another database by Redis Cli

Tags: redis

Want to migrate all keys from one database to another by **redis cli**
getting error **"NOKEY"**

```
Redis Cli >> migrate host port "" 0 5000 auth pass copy keys
"NOKEY"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the docs about [`MIGRATE`](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) to understand its usage. In any case, this command is for migrating specific keys (not patterns or all) between databases.

I suggest you consider using the original database's dump or setting up replication to copy the keys.